# Header caught and sticks after scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want the header to stick on scroll as shown here. (http://davist11.github.io/jQuery-Stickem/)
Source site (https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem)

I have a full screen video at the top of the page playing and I want to scroll and have the header stick when it hits it. Similarly there is a small border at the top on the other pages I want the scroll to miss then stick when it reaches this point.

Here is what it currently looks like

http://jsfiddle.net/wp7ornmv/

EDIT: Scroll on the HTML window

```
<div id="logo">
    </div>
    <div id="intro">

        <video autoplay loop poster="images/work/bluesky.jpg" id="bgvid">
            <source src="video/Peri_CloudLoop_BlueTV.webm" type="video/webm">
            <source src="video/Peri_CloudLoop_BlueTV_3.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="content">
            <div id="Mbackground">
                <div id="Ncontainer">
                    <div id="Ncontain">

                        <div id="Nlogo">Logo
                        </div>
                        <div id="Nmenu">
                            <div class="Nlink"><a href="url">Contact</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Nlink"><a href="url">About</a>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Nlink"><a href="index.html" class="active transition">Work</a>
                            </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="Mbackground">
                <div id="Mbody">
                <div class="Mrow">
                    <div class="Mcontainer">
                        <a href="project.html" class="transition">
                            <span class="link-spanner"></span>
                        </a>
                        <div id="Mimageone" class="Mimage">
                        </div>
                        <div id="Mborderone" class="Mborder">
                        </div>
                        <div id="Mboxone" class="Mbox">
                            <div class="Mtext">
                                <div class="Mtitle">Title
                                </div>
                                <div class="Msubtitle">Subtitle
                                </div>
                                <div class="Mdescrip">Descript
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="Meye">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <div id="footerhalf1">
        </div>
        <div id="footerhalf2">  
            <div id="footercontents">Made by
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: You can use position:fixed and a high z-index to keep a header at the top of the page when scrolling.

Comment: I want it to be caught on scroll as shown in the demo.

Answer (score 1):

This is a javascript supported behavior by stickem. You may find it [**HERE**](https://github.com/davist11/jQuery-Stickem)

Just make sure your container has a `position relative` and your sidebar has a `position:fixed; top:0; left:auto` and you will have it done.

This technique is quite common on websites running advertisements on a side panel. There is a lot more intricate information about this online and I assure you, using the source for the demo you provided along with the stickem jquery library, you will be done in no time.

Good luck

Comment: Yeah this is what I referenced in my question. I have tried implementing it to my already existing site but I can't seem to have the navigation bar remain where it currently is... Then stick when it arrives at that position. If you check my jsfiddle.

Comment: Is this the right thing to use for the navigation? Or should I use an alternative plugin?

Comment: I tried using your fiddle and nothing showed up. Your navigation bar should be outside the scope of the container and fixed to top as well. Then give the container or any following body a position:relative and top: equal to the height of the navigation bar so that the top:0 is right under the navigation.

Comment: Without testing it I can probably guess that you will need a clear:both on the navigation:after, but again, you'd have to test it and see if you even needed. In theory it should work

Comment: If you scroll down you will see the rest of the page. It is because the fullscreen video is taking up the space but not actually visible.
Yeah I understand in theory hehe, I tried in practice but can't seem to get it to work. So my fiddle was left untouched from my not working implementation of it.

Comment: I updated your fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wp7ornmv/2/ to show you the concept but quite honestly you have a lot of bad practices there that are conflicting with what you are trying to acheive. duplicated IDs and other stuff. May I suggest you look into bootstrap.

Comment: I've got most of the rest of the site working how I'd like so would be a waste of time to move it over to bootstrap. I can't see how the concept you are referring to is working. There is no JS like the example. Just the nav is fixed to the top.

Comment: I was referring to the navigation being on top and not affecting the position of the page content. You don't have to use bootstrap. That's fine, but at least don't use IDs to control your css and definitely do not duplicate them. IDs are most for server side control, specially is you are a .net developer. Clean up your code. Fix your header and footer to define your page space, and apply the stiquem jquery accordingly and you'll be fine. But without cleaning your code, your stiquem won't have a definite space to move and stick at the top.

Comment: But as you see I want the navigation to only enter after the fullscreen video. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Sorry. I had a meeting to attend to. That is a far more complicated setup. The best way is to create two sections. 1 for the video and another for the rest of the site. Then you need an anchor text somewhere where the video part of the site is being played that targets the ID for the second part. Once clicked, it navigates to the rest of the site. Look up fluid single-page websites to get an idea how it works. But it will take more effort to implement than just a few css changes from where you are now

Comment: No problem. I am reconstructing the site based around this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26915220/calculate-height-with-jquery-for-sticky-header/